# Adding new simple route does not work in Laravel project. 404 not found. Is there any way to restart, reset or rebuild laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, routes

While being on learning curve with laravel, I have created the new project and installed jetstream on it, have experimented with preprocessor's configurations, and some other basic stuff. Right now when I have added the simplest it does not work:

```
Route::get('foo', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

And all the previously added routes work fine.

Here is the whole web.php file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/



Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');


Route::get('/testcomp', function(){
    return view('testcompmain');
});

Route::get('laravelProj3/login', function(){
    return view('laravelProj3.auth.login');
});

Route::get('foo', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

If any other files are helpful here, please let me know I will post them.

Is there any way to reset, or rebuild the project to force it to work again?

What if something like this happens while I am working on real project?

Can I somehow automatically copy all files that I added to newly build working application?

Is there any way except debugging to find where is the problem?

Update #1: Here is what I have found while debugging:
"Exception has occurred.
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException: No routes found for "/foo"."

Comment: Hit & see the magic `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: @sta yes, it worked. This command has deleted file bootstrap\cache\route-v7.php. But can you explain it a bit further? Why does it happen, and what this file route-v7.php about?

Comment: This is a cache file of your route, where laravel store your cache file. Laravel also cached views & config data

Comment: Not seeing the problem at first glance, but a couple things might help. Start by returning `response("Hello World");`, instead of just the string. Pretty sure the Route handler expect an `Illuminate\Http\Response` object or a `View`, but that's about it. You could also run `php artisan route:list` to see the full path of your routes. Make sure the 'foo' one shows up at all, and is as expected. Maybe a middleware is adding a prefix or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route has been cached. It reduces all of your route registrations into a single method call within a cached file, improving the performance of route registration when registering hundreds of routes. If you want to clear the cached file, then simply hit :

```
php artisan route:clear
```

You can cache your route again by :

```
php artisan route:cache
```

For more info see the official documentation of **[Route Caching](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#route-caching)**,  **[Optimizing Views](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#optimizing-views)**, **[Environment](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/testing#environment)**